# kube-apiserver logs that certificate has expired but it's not

Tags: kubernetes, cluster

kube-apiserver pod print following log:

```
authentication.go:104] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

I already renewed all certs
[renew certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5qzR.png)

admin.conf copied to ~/.kube/config
I deleted kubelet.conf and files from /var/lib/kubelet/pki and then create new ones.
After that kubelet was restarted. I also restarted apiserver pod but it still print log that certificate is expired.
Interesting thing is that all I don't see any problems with cluster. Kubectl works as always.
I use v1.17.6 version. My cluster has 2-master and 8-worker nodes.
Any ideas?

Comment: Kind of sound like one of your kubelet being unable to check in: are your nodes all OK/ready? Pick one pod running on each node: can you properly run "kubectl logs"?

Comment: .. wait... 2 masters? both with etcd? ... Out of topic .. but you should really go with 3 (right now, if one master goes down, your etcd is out of quorum: all API's down)

Comment: yes, I can run kubectl logs with success (pod logs from each node)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I restarted all 4 static Pod of cluster by temporary removing its manifest file from /etc/kubernetes/manifests/ and moved back after 20 seconds as the documentation says.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#manual-certificate-renewal

First i removed and moved back kube-apiserver.yaml, then kube-controller-manager.yaml, after that kube-scheduler.yaml and at last the etcd.yaml.

I don't know if it works even if you delete and move them back all at once.